# How can I set HTTP header Expires on my Yii2 api module?

Tags: php, yii2

I am initializing my Api module on my class `init()` with this

```
public function init()
{
    //parent::init();
    Yii::$app->request->parsers = ['application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser'];
    Yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
    $headers->set('Expires', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + (60 * 60)));
    Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
    Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = null;
}
```

This still gives me

```
Expires → Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

**EDIT:** I have tried using php method headers below and it works. Setting application type to JSON also works only when I access header directly like this.

```
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + (60 * 60)));
```

I have tried setting this on my action. I have also thought of setting Response component Expires on my web config but do not know how to input the value. When I try setting headers property is gives me setting read only property error. What I need is to set cache for the response to my volley request on android. How can I achieve this on my module or my application?

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong, it should be :

```
$headers->set('Expires', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + (60 * 60)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need afterAction, see '\yii\base\Module'

```
<?php
namespace app\api;

use Yii;

/**
 * api module definition class
 */
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\api\controllers';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // custom initialization code goes here
    }

    public function afterAction($action, $result)
    {
        $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);
        
        // in yii, use Yii::$app->response->headers, no header()
        $response = Yii::$app->response;
        $response->headers->add('Test-Name', 'test-value');

        return $result;
    }
}
```